# Bad quality in animation EEVEE Blender 2.81a

Tags: rendering, animation

I have problem with quality on animation. When I render a picture quality is good but in animation it's very bad. I don't know how to fix this. I tryied to set samples to 800 but effect was same, should I render it on 5000 samples or more? Please help.
[image]
Picture
[image]
Video
[image]
Settings

Comment: What are your video encoding settings?

Comment: You mean this? I added new photo

Comment: Please try to set the *Output Quality* to *Perceptually lossless* and *Encoding Speed* to *Slowest*.

Comment: Thanks! Now it's much better, but quality is still not the best, increase number of samples will help?

Comment: I set 500 samples and quality was a bit better so i set 2000 but quality was same like in 500 samples, can you help me?

Comment: The number of samples doesn't affect the video encoding. Increasing the samples doesn't help if the still frames already look as they're supposed to. In order to improve the video quality even further you could use a format that supports a codec with lossless compression.

Comment: Okay, do you know which format supports it?